# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigationrail.NavigationRailView

Tags: android, gradle

I encountered the following error:
`Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigationrail.NavigationRailView`

This is layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.navigationrail.NavigationRailView
    android:id="@+id/ll_setting_nav"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/qb_px_161"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_rail_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/my_navigation_rail_fab"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view_setting_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

And this is dependencies
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'`

I try add
`configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'  }`
in gradle, but the problem is not solved

Comment: Can you add the entire stack trace as it should contain a clue to what the issue is.